# Editing 100's of ImageViews - Objective C iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

Currently in my iPhone application I have about 200 image views, and I will need to edit just about all of them specifically in my code. Do I really have to create outlets for each and every one of the imageviews, or is there an easier (quicker) way to reference and edit each imageview individually in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have so many image views? how could you fit them all in a screen?

Comment: UIScrollView would be the obvious answer to that.

Comment: `UIScrollView` would be the obvious answer, but still 200 imageViews points to a potentially poor design choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `IBOutletCollection` and then you can treat them as an array

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *imageViews;
```

you still have to make all the connection's in the nib but you only have one property for them

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- give them consequent tags and loop with `viewWithTag:` for their superview
- iterate through all of their superview's subviews and check with `[obj isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]` if selected subview is an UIImageView

These two are the first that come to mind.

Comment: -1 gag. `viewWithTag:` is a crutch for inexperienced programmers.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive feedback.

Comment: (no offense intended, btw; i just really hate that API)

Comment: @Alexander I think what Dave was trying to say is that `viewWithTag:`—while being a workable option—is just a workaround for the real design problem, and makes it too easy to keep terrible program design, layout, and architecture decisions viable.

Comment: And in related news, @ItaiFerber is psychic.